# oAuth JWT flow for multiple users

Tags: api, customer-community, oauth, jwt

I've only ever used the JWT flow for server to server integrations with a hardcoded specific user. Is it even recommended to use it with multiple users where we dynamically inject the username into the JSON object on every call ?
The use case is a service exposed behind an API that handles "passwordless" logins for customers on a mobile app, accessing Salesforce resources.

Comment: If you plan on generating JWT on your mobile app, then no, it's not a good idea.

Comment: Nop, as explained, the oAuth flow is going to be behind a server exposing a service via API to the mobile app. This service should take the username and client ID from the APP and then authenticate via JWT as that user to access its resources.

Comment: That will work but in terms of security, you're just kicking the can down the road. Attacker can reverse engineer your app and sign in as any other user.

Comment: Starting with Spring '23, the recommended option for this use case is [Headless Login](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_experiences_headless_identity_pointer.htm&release=242&type=5)